Explicitly defining a `Maybe` like `Show` instance
I've got a type something like this:
newtype Property a = Property (Maybe a)

But instead of the Show instance being like:
Just "Hello"
Just (Just "World")
Nothing

I want it to be like:
Property "Hello"
Property (Just "World")
NoProperty

I understand I could make my type like:
data Property a = Property a | NoProperty
  deriving stock Show

Instead of a newtype around Maybe, but I don't want to do that refactoring just for the show instance. I guess also I could just write a show instance that repacks my data into Property, but again, I'm interested on how to write this myself.
So I went to look at the source code for how Maybe is defined, but unfortunately I think it's defined using stock deriving: (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#line-215)
So as I didn't want to use stock deriving here, I instead tried this definition:
newtype Property a = Property (Maybe a)

instance Show a => Show (Property a) where
  showsPrec n (Property x) = case x of
    Just x -> (++ ("Property " ++ showsPrec n x ""))
    Nothing -> (++ "PropertyEmpty")
    
main = do 
  print (Just (Just 5))
  print (Just 5)
  print (Property (Just (Just 5)))
  print (Property (Just 5))

Which gave the following output:
Just (Just 5)
Just 5
Property Just 5
Property 5

This is just off. I want the output to be:
Just (Just 5)
Just 5
Property (Just 5)
Property 5

Basically, I want the (Just 5) in Property (Just 5) to be parenthesised, but not the 5 in Property 5.
I'm guessing I need some sort of check on the precedent n, and to add brackets conditionally, but I'm not sure what this check is. How can I write this Show instance to get what I want?
Edit/Answer:
I've found changing:
showsPrec n x ""

to
showsPrec 11 x ""

Seems to work.
But why 11?!
The docs say 10 is function precedence. Yet 10 doesn't work.
Why do I have to "turn it up to 11?".

You could data Property a = NoProperty | Property a deriving Show in a standalone file, then use -ddump-deriv to see the derived instance, and tweak it for your custom newtype.

I never remember how to do this properly, but the official documentation for the Show class has a good explanation and example, so I always just look that up and follow its pattern.
The job of the n argument is essentially to keep track of the "precedence level" of the surrounding expression. If it's low enough, then you can splice in an expression of higher-precedence operators without surrounding parentheses.1
Function application is equivalent to precedence level 10. So if the surrounding context is arguments to any lower precedence level operator (i.e. any operator at all), then you don't need parentheses. So there needs to be an n value that would indicate that direct function application wouldn't need parentheses, but any other operator expression would.
But sometimes the surrounding environment is even higher precedence than that, and even function application requires wrapping parentheses to indicate the correct structure. That's exactly the situation you're in with an expression like Property (Just 5). The n for the showsPrec call that renders the Just 5 needs to indicate that parentheses are required even though Just 5 is the highest possible precedence level.
So we need 2 different n values for those two situations. 10 is the first one, while the second one uses 11 for the n value2. Your situation is the second, so that's what you need to pass.
Note that passing through the n you received (as in your original code) is quite wrong. The n you receive indicates the precedence you would need to have to avoid wrapping parentheses around yourself; it should have been set basd on the precedence level of the containing expression. The n you pass through to recursive showsPrec calls for sub-expressions is to control whether they need parentheses, which means they need it to be set to the precedence level of this expression (which is the expression they are contained in), not the precedence level of the the expression that contains this expression. So the n value you pass down should be a constant determined by the precedence level of your type's data constructor. It has no connection at all to the n value you receive; whether your sub-expressions need parentheses does not depend on whether you needed parentheses around the whole expression.
There is a helper function showParen for assisting you in wrapping the result of showsPrec in parentheses when required. But it's much easier to understand how to use it by looking at the example in the main docs for the Show class.

1 For example when a Show instance is called on to generate 2 * 3, if the surrounding expression is Just _ then it should use parentheses (producing "(2 * 3)" so that the whole string becomes "Just (2 * 3)". But if the surrounding expression is 1 + _, then it doesn't need parentheses (and should produce "2 * 3" so that the whole string becomes "1 + 2 * 3").
2 There is no specific reason the "always use parentheses" value had to be 11 rather than 10 (which is one reason I always have to look this up). The convention the designers of Show chose is that the n parameter is the precedence level an application would need to have to avoid parentheses (function application has precedence 10, and nothing has precedence 11 or higher, so that's what you use to force parentheses no matter what). They could have instead used the convention that n is the precedence level of the surrounding context, and n+1 is the precedence level you need to have to skip parentheses. That would make 10 be the "always use parentheses" level.
The convention we actually use requires the "always use parentheses" level to be one higher than the maximum precedence level, but allows the "you never need parentheses" value to be the lowest possible precedence level. The alternative convention would have required the "you never need parentheses" value to be one lower than the lowest precedence level (so -1). Whichever way they went, there would need to be one "out of range" value at either the bottom or the top; there's simply one more possible value for n than there are precedence levels. There's no huge difference at the time you're designing how Show works, so they just picked one and now that's the convention we use.
